# How to prevent a DLL from being unloaded by the app that uses it?

Tags: c++, dll

I created a DLL in C++ named MyDLL.dll.
MyDLL.dll exported interface outside as following:
Here is my dll code:

```
 CMyAdapter g_DllImp;

 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  dwReason,
    LPVOID pReserved
)
{
    if (DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH == dwReasonForCall)
        g_DllImp.m_hModule = hModule;
    else if (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH == dwReasonForCall)
        g_DllImp.m_hModule = NULL;

    return TRUE;
}
 __declspec(dllexport) HRESULT GetVersion(
    tVersion* pVersion
)
{
    return g_DllImp.GetApiVersion(
                pVersion);
}
```

Here is the example of main app:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  HMODULE module = LoadLibrary(L"MyDLL.dll");
....
  // call the interface of MyDLL.dll
  GetVersion(&pVersion);
  return 0;
}
```

unfortunately, my main app is crash due to unknown reason. but according to Dump Crash File the crash is MyDLL is unloaded:

```
0289cc24 52e4577e <Unloaded_MyDLL.dll>+0x15728
```

I must use the code to catch exception:

```
__try{} 
 __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
```

My question is:

Should I use __try{} __except() in interface of MyDLL or in main app?
 Which one is better?

Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: How does the statically compiled `GetVersion()` call have anything to do with the interface of your DLL? Are you sure it ever got loaded? called?

Comment: maybe it is just unloaded due to the crash.

Comment: Use a debugger to identify what happens at `LoadLibrary`, `GetVersion`, and when the crash occurs.

Comment: *"my main app is crash due to unknown reason..."* - You need to provide an accurate error message or a stack trace. Without an accurate message or stack trace, we can't help you. Why do you think the crash is due to the DLL being unloaded? Also, you should call [FreeLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not loaded the dll successfully,you must make sure that the module of DLL is eligible before you use it .

Answer (score 0):

It's not the responsibility of your DLL. All users of your DLL are responsible for matching `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` calls.

To debug the broken executable, try Dependency Walker.